# Trying to use doubles in C++. Not sure where I'm going wrong

Tags: c++

So I'm writing this program that takes an input and tries to get the input to 1 by either dividing it by 2 if it's even, or multiplying it by 3 and then adding 1. It's giving me this error when I try to compile it:

```
bigbeno37@vm-0:~/GitHub2$ g++ NumberGenerator1.cpp
NumberGenerator1.cpp:1:2: warning: #import is a deprecated GCC extension [-Wdeprecated]
NumberGenerator1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
NumberGenerator1.cpp:13:5: error: ‘inputNumberClone’ was not declared in this scope
NumberGenerator1.cpp:16:26: error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to    binary ‘operator%’
NumberGenerator1.cpp:19:26: error: cannot convert ‘int(int (*)(void*), void*, int,     void*, ...)throw ()’ to ‘double’ in assignment
NumberGenerator1.cpp:24:26: error: cannot convert ‘int(int (*)(void*), void*, int,  void*, ...)throw ()’ to ‘double’ in assignment
```

This is my code

```
#import <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;

double inputNumber = 0;
double inputerNumberClone = 0;
double stepsClone = 0;

cin >> inputNumber;
inputNumberClone = inputNumber;

for(double steps = 0; inputNumber != 1; steps++){
    if(inputNumber % 2 == 0){
        inputNumber = inputNumber / 2;

        stepsClone = clone;
    }else{
        inputNumber = inputNumber * 3;
        inputNumber++;

        stepsClone = clone;
    }
}

cout << "It takes " << stepsClone << " to get to 1 from " << inputNumberClone << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You have several typos. Change `inputNumberClone` to `inputerNumberClone`, `clone` is not defined in your code and this is the name of standard `libc` function.

Comment: Start with using `#include` instead of `#import`

Comment: This program attempts to implement code to test the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), which says that for every number, the sequence of operations eventually reaches 1.  This hasn't been proved; it has been demonstrated for all numbers up to some rather significantly large numbers.

Comment: I think the first step would be to go through the error messages and at least resolve the first few that you can understand. I think that at least one or two in your example can be readily fixed (maybe with some reading of related docs). Then when you fix those you might be surprised to find that several other errors go away, too. This is a common situation in programming, where one error will 'cascade' into a bunch of seemingly bizarre errors that are really a result of the first. So try to at least fix the first errors that make sense, then see if a recompile looks better.

Comment: Note that the `inputNumber != 1` is likely to always be true. You need to use a range instead, from say 1.0001 and 0.9999. Otherwise you'll likely loop forever. `inputNumber > 1.0001 && inputNumber < 0.9999`. Also you probably don't need steps unless you want to limit the number of iterations in which case you need to make it an integer and put a test for it too... Note that goes for the fmod() result which is not likely going to be exactly zero.

Answer (score 4):

- `#include` not `#import`.
- You wrote `inputerNumberClone` instead of `inputNumberClone`.
- You have to use `fmod` for `double`s instead of `%`.

Answer (score 4):

1. `#include` instead of `#import`
2. Correct typos `inputerNumberClone` instead of `inputNumberClone` and `steps` instead of `clone`
3. Use integer instead of double - there is no sense using double in your code.

You are getting an integer as input. Then you are dividing it by `2` if it is even, so the result is also an integer.

If you are not getting an integer as input think, what means i.e. `1.5 % 2`.

Double is stored in memory as sign, exponent and fraction and it is not 100% precise. So instead of `2` you can get `1.99...9` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Doubles can't be used for `operator%`, only ints can.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a typo:

```
double inputerNumberClone = 0;
```

It should be `inputNumberClone`.

The other problem is the modulo operation cannot be applied on doubles. It requires integral types.

So you either change the values from `double` to `int` or use the `std::fmod` function.

```
if(std::fmod(inputNumber, 2) == 0) {
}
```

The other error is here:

```
stepsClone = clone;
```

What is clone?

Answer (score 2):

For starters have a look the spelling of inputerNumberClone.

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberGenerator1.cpp:13:5: error: ‘inputNumberClone’ was not declared in this scope
```

You made a typo in the declaration and it has no idea what "inputNumberClone" is.

```
NumberGenerator1.cpp:16:26: error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to    binary ‘operator%’
```

You're trying to use modular arithmetic on doubles, while it is only allowed on integers in c++. There probably is a function in math.h (probably `rem` or something like remainder) that does what you want. The % operator is a special thing as it's an instruction for integers, but it's multiple (so logically a function) for doubles (at time of C's design).

```
NumberGenerator1.cpp:19:26: error: cannot convert ‘int(int (*)(void*), void*, int,     void*, ...)throw ()’ to ‘double’ in assignment
NumberGenerator1.cpp:24:26: error: cannot convert ‘int(int (*)(void*), void*, int,  void*, ...)throw ()’ to ‘double’ in assignment
```

There is a function you get from the Linux header files called `clone`. It thinks you want to use this function here. Rename to your variable `steps` instead to avoid both colliding with the function and this error.